# integer S transform

Tags: arithmetic

I found the following integer transform, where all variables $x_0,x
_1$ and $x_2$ are integers:

$
y_0=x_1+floor(\frac{1}{4}(x_0+2x_1+x_2))\\
 y_1=x_2-x_1\\
 y_2=x_0-x_1
$

The inverse transform is following:

$
x_0=s+y_2\\
x_1=s\\
x_2=s+y_1\\
$

where $s=y_0-floor(\frac{1}{4}(y_1+y_2))$

How can modify the transform to have $y_1$ or $y_2$ to be equal with $floor(\frac{x_2-x_1}{2})$ or $floor(\frac{x_0-x_1}{2})$?